# broadcasting and receiving in Delphi

Tags: delphi-7

I want to send a broadcast UDP message in my project between 2 forms.

i need to know how to receive and broadcast ? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have access to the Indy components (such as `TIdUDPClient`)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send a message within your app between 2 forms
either use SendMessage, which returns after the message is processed
or PostMessage, which returns immediately, before the message is processed

UDP is for sending message between 2 different computers
but, you might want to switch to TCP/IP protocol, if you want to be certain the message arrives